# Table cell <td> top and bottom padding in HTML5 ONLY - where is it coming from?

Tags: css, html

I am working on a client's site that was built using **XHTML 1.0 Transitional**. I'm changing it to **HTML5**.

I run into a problem when I switch the Doctype declaration to HTML5 however: **table cells acquire top and bottom padding of about 2px**.

But here's the strange thing: it **isn't padding**! While it **displays as padding** (green) in Chrome's Developer Tools, the *Metrics* section of DT clearly shows that there isn't any padding.

So if it's not padding, what is it? And where does it come from?

I've tried zeroing everything but to no avail.

**HTML:**

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="/somepage1">Link</a></td>
        <td><a href="/somepage2">Link</a></td>
        <td><a href="/somepage3">Link</a></td>
        <!-- etc etc -->
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
table, tbody, tr, th, td {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  line-height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: url(somebackground-image);
}
```

I tried copying everything over to jsFiddle but I couldn't recreate the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is apparently an issue related to HTML5.

**[This page](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50633)** relates specifically to Chrome, but I observed the behaviour in IE9 also.

I removed the **line-height** declaration from the **table cells**, but that wasn't enough - I also had to set the **table line-height** to **0px**.

```
table {
    line-height: 0px;
}

td {
    /* make sure no line height is set on td */
    /* line-height: somepx; */
}
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: It is not an issue, just correct handling of the default line-height in strict mode. The same happens with any doctype declaration that doesn’t trigger quirks mode.

Comment: A bit more precisely, it happens in Standards mode (with any Strict doctype or HTML5 doctype), but not in Quirks mode (e.g. with no doctype) and not in Almost Standards mode (XHTML Transitional doctype, HTML 4.x Transitional with DTD, or Frameset doctypes).